# Eigenvalue problem $y''+py=0$, $y(-2)=0$, $y(2)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The problem states to find the non-negative solutions to the eigenvalue problem given by $y''+py=0$ where p is a parameter which may be varied.

Solving this differential equation for the general solution yields:
$y=A\cos( p^{1/2} x) + B\sin( p^{1/2} x) $

furthermore:
$y'=-A p^{1/2}\sin(p^{1/2}x)+ B p^{1/2}\cos(p^{1/2}x)$

Using the boundary conditions given $y(-2)=0$ and $y'(2)=0$
we may express the problem in the following matrix notation:

$ D * {[A,B]}^{T}=0$

where $D$ is the matrix with a top row of:
$\cos( 2 p^{1/2}), -\sin(2 p^{1/2})$

and a bottom row of:
$- p^{1/2}\sin(2 p^{1/2}), p^{1/2}\cos( 2 p^{1/2}) $

In my textbook it is written that the eigenvalues are the values of p which satisfy $\det(D)=0$

hence:
$p^{1/2}\cos^2(2 p^{1/2})-p^{1/2}\sin^2(2 p^{1/2})=0$

assuming $p^{1/2}$ doesnt equal 0 (which it does not) and adding $\sin^2(2 p^{1/2})$ to both sides of the equation yields:

$\cos^2(2 p^{1/2})=\sin^2(2 p^{1/2})$

we may take the square root of both sides to get:
$|\cos(2p^{1/2})|=|\sin(2p^{1/2})|$
from which it follows that:
$1=|\tan(2p^{1/2})|$

this is satisfied when:
$2p^{1/2}= {n\pi}/4$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$
hence $p^{1/2}=n\pi/8$

My confusion begins here, and may be an error in the answer provided by the textbook.

For even values of n the textbook provides the eigenfunction:
$y=\cos(n\pi x/8) - \sin(n\pi x/8)$

however, for an answer:
$y=A\cos(n\pi x/8)+B\sin(n\pi x/8)$
to satisfy $y(-2)=0$
it follows that:
$0=A\cos(-n\pi/4)+B\sin(-n\pi/4)$
for an even n this means either the first or second term will be zero; thus the coefficient of the nonzero term must be zero. So, is the answer provided in the book incorrect?

For odd n I received the same answer as the book of:
$y=A\cos(n\pi x/8)+A\sin(n\pi x/8)$